# How to make Opera open magnet links?

Tags: transmission, opera

I have Transmission 2.52 and Opera 11.64 x64, when I try to open a magnet link from The Pirate Bay, Opera says it cant recognize that protocol, how to set up?

Comment: http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2011/01/tweak-opera-to-befriend-transmission/

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to fix this issue with the latest version? I just started having problems with this yesterday once i opened bitorrent to find some older files.. now it is having this issue unless i just manually copy the link into utorrent..

Answer (score 9):

Go to preferences -> advanced -> programs -> add
Protocol = magnet

Choose your action:

Then tick *Open with other application* (and copy the line from below):

```
 /usr/bin/transmission %s
```

Parameter: leave empty (unchecked) *Open in terminal*

You need to wait 3 or 4 minutes until the peers list is completely loaded!

Comment: it works for me when u use `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk %s` instead.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to follow this documentation :
http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2011/01/tweak-opera-to-befriend-transmission/

It seems that you should just go to programs, add the protocol and open with transmission, and add '%s' in the parameters field.