# Magnet Links in Opera

Tags: bittorrent, opera

I know you can open .torrent files using Opera, but not magnet protocol links. I have tried "Opera > Settings > Preferences > Advanced > Programs > Add > Protocol" and typed "magnet", but I don't know what to put in "Open With Other Application". I don't want to install a Bittorrent Client. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

When a web browser opens a magnet link, that causes it to open *the application needed to access the content offered through the link.* For bittorrent magnet links, it opens your bittorrent application,

So [configuring Opera for magnet links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143453/how-to-make-opera-open-magnet-links) does not eliminate the need to have a bittorrent client. You need one, unless Opera is able to *act as a bittorrent client itself*. I do not believe this is the case, though it's imaginably possible that such a feature could be added in a later version. (You would still not be able to open a torrent magnet link without a bittorrent client though; this would just mean that your web browser was *also* your bittorrent client.)